# Android CameraX - Camera preview freezes on first call to captureUseCase.takePicture()

Tags: android, kotlin, camera, firebase-mlkit, android-camerax

I am using android camera X api to capture selfie image by analyzing the face detected.
The app captures more than 5 images if the face is inside rectangular frame show on the screen.

The issue is, camera preview freezes(few seconds) when capturing image for the first time.

I am using the below code to set up camera provider in my activity.

// preview use case

```
internal fun bindPreviewUseCase(previewView: PreviewView) {
    Util.printDebugLog("Binding camera preview use case.")
    if (previewUseCase != null) {
        cameraProvider.unbind(previewUseCase)
    }
    previewUseCase = Preview.Builder()
        .setTargetResolution(Size(480, 800))
        .build()
    previewUseCase!!.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.createSurfaceProvider())
    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, previewUseCase)
}
```

// analysis use case

```
internal fun bindAnalysisUseCase(graphicOverlay: GraphicOverlay) {
        Util.printDebugLog("Binding camera analysis use case.")
        if (analysisUseCase != null) {
            cameraProvider.unbind(analysisUseCase)
        }
        imageProcessor?.stop()
        try {
            val faceDetectorOptions: FaceDetectorOptions = getFaceDetectorOptionsForLivePreview()
            imageProcessor =
                LiveFaceDetectorProcessor(context, faceDetectorOptions, faceFrameProcessListener)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Viola.listener.onFaceDetectionFailed(
                FaceDetectionError.IMAGE_PROCESSOR_ERROR,
                "Can not create image processor: ${e.localizedMessage}"
            )
            return
        }
        val builder = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
        builder.setTargetResolution(Size(480, 800))
        analysisUseCase = builder.build()
        needUpdateGraphicOverlayImageSourceInfo = true
        analysisUseCase!!.setAnalyzer(
            ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context),
            ImageAnalysis.Analyzer { imageProxy: ImageProxy ->
                if (needUpdateGraphicOverlayImageSourceInfo) {
                    val isImageFlipped =
                        lensFacing == CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
                    val rotationDegrees = imageProxy.imageInfo.rotationDegrees
                    if (rotationDegrees == 0 || rotationDegrees == 180) {
                        graphicOverlay.setImageSourceInfo(
                            imageProxy.width, imageProxy.height, isImageFlipped
                        )
                    } else {
                        graphicOverlay.setImageSourceInfo(
                            imageProxy.height, imageProxy.width, isImageFlipped
                        )
                    }
                    needUpdateGraphicOverlayImageSourceInfo = false
                }
                try {
                    imageProcessor!!.processImageProxy(imageProxy, graphicOverlay)
                } catch (e: MlKitException) {
                    Viola.listener.onFaceDetectionFailed(
                        FaceDetectionError.IMAGE_PROCESSOR_ERROR,
                        "Failed to process image: ${e.localizedMessage}"
                    )
                }
            }
        )
        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, analysisUseCase)
    }
```

// capture use case

```
internal fun bindCaptureUseCase(previewView: PreviewView) {
    Util.printDebugLog("Binding camera capture use case.")
    if (captureUseCase != null) {
        cameraProvider.unbind(captureUseCase)
    }
    val rotation = previewView.display.rotation
    captureUseCase = ImageCapture.Builder()
        .setCaptureMode(ImageCapture.CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
        .setTargetResolution(Size(960, 1280))
        .setTargetRotation(rotation)
        .build()
    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, captureUseCase)
}
```

//capture

```
internal fun takePicture(callback: CaptureCallback) {
    Util.printDebugLog("Capturing current frame.")
    val diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastCaptureTime
    if (diff > captureDelay) {
        if (!isCaptureInProgress) {
            if (captureUseCase == null) {
                return
            }
            isCaptureInProgress = true
            lastCaptureTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context)
            //TODO remove
            val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

            captureUseCase!!.takePicture(
                executor,
                object : ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
                    override fun onCaptureSuccess(image: ImageProxy) {
                        val timeElapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
                        Util.printDebugLog("Image captured, producing bitmap from image proxy. $timeElapsed")
                        val bitmap: Bitmap =
                            BitmapUtil.getBitmap(image, image.imageInfo.rotationDegrees)!!
                        image.close()
                        callback.onCaptured(bitmap)
                        isCaptureInProgress = false
                        super.onCaptureSuccess(image)
                    }

                    override fun onError(exception: ImageCaptureException) {
                        super.onError(exception)
                        isCaptureInProgress = false
                        Util.printDebugLog("Unable to capture: ${exception.localizedMessage}")
                    }
                })
        }
    } else {
        Util.printDebugLog("Capture called before minimum delay.Ignoring capture call.")
    }
}
```

// dependencies used

```
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-beta07"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha14"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.0-beta07"
```

// time taken for each capture(in milliseconds)

image 1 -> 2396
image 2 -> 411
image 3 -> 356
image 4 -> 386
image 5 -> 345

Comment: You executor for running camera. here you can find https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/architecture

Comment: sorry I didn't get u, could u please explain a bit more

Comment: One issue I'm seeing in your code is you're using the main executor for analysis, it would be better to use a worker thread for analysis, so as not to do the frame processing on the main thread, since the analyzer may be receiving multiple frames per second.

Comment: I tried  moving the analyzer use case to background thread using private val executorService: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4). It reduces the freezing issue significantly but issue still there sometimes.